# Examples that use Reference Classes effectively

Tags: r, oop, pass-by-reference

I am interested in examples that effectively use the new Reference Classes.

In general, R has a more functional style of programming, not really depending on Object Oriented Programming concepts like inheritance and OOP design patterns (although some of these design patterns have their functional equivalent or are natively supported in R). In addition, reference classes circumvent the pass-by-value problems that cause large object to be copied when an object is modified inside a function, potentially using lots of RAM.

I am not looking for a list of packages or functions, but concrete examples, with bonus points for benchmarks wich prove your point objectively. In case of a OOP code example, please objectively explain why this OOP code is better than the functional equivalent.

Comment: This is not constructive in that you are soliciting list-like answers and there can not be a definitive answer here. Care to rephrase? [It pains me to say this as I too would like to know a good package that uses reference classes ...]

Comment: I tried to rephrase the question, is this more in line with SO requirements @GavinSimpson?

Comment: FYI large objects are copied when modified, not when passed to a function

Comment: This is still too vague for [so]. Is there something specific you'd like to see? That would help focus the question and would have an Answer.

Comment: I liked the question but felt that it did not meet the guidelines of stackoverflow.  I voted to close.

Comment: I agree with @TylerRinker, and right now I cannot provide any more specifics to make it fit the SO format more. If I have a more concrete question, I'll try and reopen.